# How to reset local variables to original value?

Tags: lua, scope

While scripting a bot for IOS, I want to use a specific coordinate to check location of my current screen status. I will be doing this by using a command to call the rgb color of a coordinate. Here's an example, assume that     `print` will return the rgb.

---

```
local x=100
local y=200

function getxy()
   print(x .. "," .. y)
end

function example()
   x=200
   y=300
   getxy()
end

function example2()
   x=300
   y=400
   getxy()
end

getxy()
example()
getxy()
example2()
```

---

If you run this it will return 
100,200
200,300
200,300
300,400

Is it possible to call the x and y inside of the `example()` without overwriting  the local x and local y outside of the functions?

---

Edit: my solution

```
local x=100
local y=200

function getxy()
   print(x .. "," .. y)
end

function home()
   x=100
   y=200
end

function example()
   x=200
   y=300
   getxy()
   home()
end

function example2()
   x=300
   y=400
   getxy()
   home()
end

getxy()
example()
getxy()
example2()
```

Now running this will return 100,200 200,300 100,200 300,400

### Which is exactly what I want.

So I added another function named `home()`. Is this efficient for what I'm trying to accomplish or should I place the `home()` call inside of the `getxy()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following example

```
local x,y = 100,200;
function output(x,y)
    print('x =',x,', y =',y);
end

function home(o)
    local x,y = x+50,y+50; -- this uses the declared x,y but assigns them to a local variables named x,y... so original x,y won't be rewritten..
    o = (o and output(x,y)); -- lazy call to output instead doing if then end..
end
function example1(o)
    local x,y = 15,20;
    o = (o and output(x,y));
end
function example2(o)
    local x,y = x*x/(x+x),y*y/(y+y);
    o = (o and output(x,y))
end
print('original variables value =',x,y); -- original variables value = 100 200
home(true); -- x = 150, y = 250
example1(true); -- x = 15, y = 20
example2(true); -- x = 50, y = 100
print('variables value =',x,y); -- variables value = 100 200
```

Comment: I'm still almost brand new to logic and programming in general. Can you explain what the `(o)` after the function does? And I'm failing to understand your local in `example2`.

Comment: `o` is a local variable, this is a 'hack' to call the function. It basically do
`o = if o then return output(x,y) end` but in shorter way.
Alternative we could just do `if (o) then output(x,y); end`.

About example2
first of all it gets the x value (100), multiplies it by x (100), which is 1000 and divides it by 2x (200) so output is 50, then it sets a local variable (named `x`, new one, does not override our main x,y) with the value (of 50).